# To "late file the form" vs to "file the form late"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, legalese

I'm wondering about the differences between to:

> Late file the form

and

> File the form late

Specifically, how can the grammar of the form in A1 below be described? Is an adjective modifying a verb? Is that even possible? Is "late" in "late file" an adverb?

The A2 form (with hyphen) also has many Google hits. Is a hyphen required?

More importantly, why even use A1 (or A2) when A3 seems much more natural word order? Is this simply an idiosyncratic style of legalese that can be ignored for the sake of preferring Plain English? Or is A1 somehow semantically different from A3?

Is this A1 (and A2-A3) word order used for any other adjectives, especially any outside legal contexts?

> A1. If you **late** file the form
>
> A2. If you **late**-file the form
>
> A3. If you file your the form **late**
>
> B1. If you timely file the form
>
> B2. If you timely-file the form (I see no Google hits for this version
>   with a hyphen.)
>
> B3. If you file the form timely (Seems totally unnatural.)

Comment: @mplungan Yes. I agree that this usage is not idiomatic. That's why I'm asking. Some tax and law people seem to use this odd word order, though. Here is an example webpage: https://www.bnncpa.com/industries/tax_exempt_organizations/blog/late_filing_990_n_whats_the_big_deal

Comment: Please see my amended answer

Answer (score 1):

Most of your examples are not idiomatically correct English.

Here are some correct versions of what you seem to be trying to convey:

- *If you file your form (too) late...*
- *If you are late filing the form...*
- *If you file your form in time...*
- *If you file your form in a timely manner...*

IRS.GOV use late-filing and late file which indeed may be legalese:

- *By properly filing this form, a taxpayer will avoid the late-filing penalty.*
- *In addition to the deposit penalties, you will also be subject to
  penalties if you late file your Form*